# Newbie: OOP working with different class-datatypes and loop through them

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, visual-studio, vb.net

I'm relatively new to OOP. Let's say I have three different objects/classes defined, like:

```
Public Class Part
    Private m_Name As String = ""
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
    End Property

    something...
End Class

Public Class Assembly 
    Private m_Name As String = ""
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
    End Property

    something...
End Class

Public Class Drawing
    Private m_Name As String = ""
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
    End Property

    something...
End Class
```

Now I have a list of all instances of those objects in another class, like:

```
Public Class Main
    Private m_ListOfObjects As List(Of Objects)
    Private Sub run()
       something...
    End Sub
End Class
```

Imagine a code which adds each instance of those three classes (Part, Assembly and Drawing) to this `m_ListOfObjects`. Now I have a loop which loops trough the whole list, like:

```
Dim Obj As Object
For Each Obj In m_ListObObjects
   Debug.Print(Obj.Name)
End For
```

My questions is now: IntelliSense is not able to show me if the property `Name` exists for the Object `Obj`. Well that's clear because Visual Studio does not know that I will use the classes `Part`, `Assembly` and `Drawing` for. How can I solve that issue?

It feels like a hacky way when I use something like this:

```
CType(Obj, Part).Name
```

Then Visual Studio knows that I refer to the `Part` Class, but what can I do if I loop through different objects in a list and refer to a property each class will have? Or maybe my approach is completely off the track of OOP? Do I miss the opportunity to implement an interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your named objects either need

```
Inherits abstractClass
```

or

```
Implements interfaceclass.name
```

Make whichever one you pick and give it a `Name` method with no implementation.

Then `main` needs either

```
Private m_ListOfObjects As List(Of abstractClass)
```

or

```
Private m_ListOfObjects As List(Of interfaceclass)
```

and suddenly calling `Name` works. This is polymorphism. It's a big part of OOP.

The reason it didn't work before is because vb.net doesn't support [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Therefor you can't just discover that each object has a `Name` property as you call it. At compile time you have to make some kind of promise that it will be there every time. You don't make that promise if it's only a list of type [Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-8.0). Sure `Name` is there, waiting, this time, but vb.net want's you to promise it'll be there. That way it can complain as soon as it sees that promise broken. It doesn't have to wait for your call. It can complain as soon as you say you want to put some nameless thing in the list.

Comment: Thank you. If I have variables that each class will need. I would make a base class/abstract class which declares this variables, like `name` and which will be inherited by the three object classes? Specific variables which only occurs in some of those three objects would be implemented with an interface or what's the strategy here?

Comment: Funny you should mention the word [strategy](https://dev.to/hamsheed993/in-depth-look-strategy-design-pattern-in-net-core-5d09).

Comment: @SturmGhost: When you want to reuse something (property, method) across multiple classes in a way that you can iterate over all of its usages, you need to declare it in a reusable component (abstract class, interface) and then have your classes implement the component. If you can then guarantee that your objects polymorphically adhere to this component, the compiler is satisfied that it will reliably be able to access the thing (method, property) that you wanted to reusably access.